# Why does Diffie-Hellman need be a cyclic group?

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, group-theory

Why is Diffie-Hellman [defined on a cyclic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Generalization_to_finite_cyclic_groups)? Doesn't it work for any commutative operation which the inverse is hard to find?

Say Alice and Bob agree in a public prime $c$ and both choose a secret prime $a$ respectively $b$

Alice sends $ac$ to Bob and Bob $bc$ to Alice.

Alice then multiplies $a$ with bobs message $bc$ yielding $abc$
Bob then multiplies $b$ with Aice's message $ac$ yield $bac$

which are the same due to commutativity and associativity. Hence they now share a common secret $abc$.

It is hard for Eve to factorize $ac$ and $bc$ into its original primes $a,b,c$  and Eve hasn't got enough information to construct $abc$  so why isn't this a valid Diffie-Hellman key-exchange?

Comment: Eve divides $ac$ by $c$.

Comment: Or multiplies like this: $(ac)\cdot(bc)/(c)$ to get the shared "secret"

Comment: @yyyyyyy: "the inverse is hard to find"; that implies that the "division problem", that is, given $b$ and $a$, find $c$ such that $a \times c = b$, is hard.

Comment: Related questions: [Diffie-Hellman on infinite groups](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22530/diffie-hellman-on-infinite-groups) and [How does the wider cryptographic community view non-abelian group based cryptography?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/how-does-the-wider-cryptographic-community-view-non-abelian-group-based-cryptogr)

Comment: @poncho From the notation up there and the lack of definition of the group, you could assume that to be $\mathbb{Z}$ or a subgroup of that and consider the factorization problem as hard - which is only true if you don't publish one of factors previously. And in that case division is easy. Regarding the question: If you go with the standard DH notation ($g^a,g^b,g^{ab}$) and base the chosen elements on a single generating element $g$, you operate on a cyclic group if it is finite. If there are multiple generating elements, you either have a problem with soundness or end up with standard DH.

Comment: @tylo: yeah, we read the problem differently; I interpreted the operation $ab$ as "some unspecified operator that meets the requirements of commutative and uninvertability"; you interpreted it (as he talked about secret primes) as the standard multiplication operator over the integers (which, as you pointed out, doesn't meet his uninvertibility requirements).

Answer (score 3):

Diffie-Hellman operates in a cyclic group by definition: the elements $g, g^a, g^b, g^{ab}$ are in the cyclic group generated by $g$. Technically, a monoid is sufficient, but since cryptography mostly operates in finite structures, you get a group anyway.

In your example, you operate in the cyclic group $c\mathbf{Z}$, and as you were told in the comments, Diffie-Hellman is not secure in this group because an attacker knows $c$ and $ac$, and can thus obtain $a$, and from $a$ and $bc$ can obtain the secret $abc$.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is diffie-hellman defined on a cyclic group[0]? Doesn't it work for any commutative operation which the inverse is hard to find?

No, you need associativity as well; once you have that, your idea would work fine, once we find a semigroup (that's what we call sets with an operator that is associative) with the appropriate properties.

That's the sticky point - what is an appropriate semigroup?  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: One could work with a commutative [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) a[ction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) instead of a semigroup. $\;$